# Cat & dog eggnog equivalent

Tags: cats, dogs, drinking

Is there an eggnog equivalent for cats and/or dogs? It’s getting close to the holidays and people might want to give their pets a holiday drink as a treat. What can I give them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What's not safe

Cats and dogs cannot tolerate alcohol. You should not give any foods or drinks that contain alcohol to your pets.

Milk or cream (which is one ingedient in egg nog) often causes digestion problems in adult pets, just as in an lactose intolerant human.

Most of the typical winter spices are also not well tolerated, especially by cats. So even a glass of non-alcoholic egg nog or punsh might not be the best idea.

### Safe alternatives

Our pets love meat. If you want to make a special treat for them, consider **making a broth** without spices.

Don't use instant broth, there's far too much salt in it to be healthy for a pet. Instead, collect all the leftover bones, cartilages, cutoffs or uneaten bits from your holiday meal, put it in a pot, barely cover it with water and let it simmer for 1 - 4 hours. Do not add salt or spices. Let it cool to room temperature. **Never feed cooked bones to your pets**, they can splinter and cause internal injuries.

If you want to achieve the texture of egg nog, you can add a tablespoon of instant potato mash to the still hot broth. Look at the ingredients of the potato mash, it **must not contain onion or garlic**.

If making a broth is too much work or you don't have the ingredients, you can also crack a **raw egg** (provided that it's fresh), add a teaspoon of cooking oil and whip the mixture up. Again, don't add any salt or spices.

Comment: Thanks, but I’m thinking of the non-alcoholic Version myself any. Not a bad attempt actually though.

Comment: @AbrahamRay glancing at a sample recipe for NA eggnog, the sugar, milk, cream, and spices would all be bad choices to give your pet. (Note that this leaves egg as the only ingredient that would be safe.)

Answer (score 2):

You can buy "Pawsecco" for dogs and cats that you add to their food. You can find this on Amazon or in pet shops. You can also find doggy beer which is basically the same thing.

Or you can make your dog some chicken broth and let him/her drink it when it has cooled down as a treat.

Here is a link:
https://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/pawsecco-still-rose-wine-for-dogs-and-cats-250ml